# When creating a virtual directory and converting it to a WebApplication, why does the output show two entries

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, iis

I created a PowerShell script to create a Virtual Directory and convert it to a WebApplication, with an existing physical path.
It works but I find it strange that the output shows two entries, when converting it to a WebApplication.

```
Name PhysicalPath       
---- ------------       
v2   E:\inetpub\MyWebsite\v2
v2   E:\inetpub\MyWebsite\v2
```

I tried different ways of creating the Virtual Folder and the WebApplication.

```
function Create-VirtualDirectory-With-AppPool {
    Param (
    [string] $WebSiteName,
    [string] $VirtualFolderName,
    [string] $AppPoolName
    )
    $PhysicalPathWebSite = (Get-Website -Name $WebSiteName | Select-Object).PhysicalPath
    $PhysicalPathVirtDir = "$PhysicalPathWebSite\$VirtualFolderName"

    Write-Host "The following will be created:"
    Write-Host "- Virtual folder: $WebSiteName\$VirtualFolderName with physical path: $PhysicalPathVirtDir"
    Write-Host "- Application: IIS:\Sites\$WebSiteName\$VirtualFolderName"
    Read-Host "Press enter to continue (Ctrl-c to abort)"
        
    New-WebVirtualDirectory -Site $WebSiteName -Name $VirtualFolderName -PhysicalPath $PhysicalPathVirtDir
    # Other attempt, same result:
    #New-Item "IIS:\Sites\$WebSiteName\$VirtualFolderName" -type VirtualDirectory -physicalPath $PhysicalPathVirtDir

    ConvertTo-WebApplication "IIS:\Sites\$WebSiteName\$VirtualFolderName"
    # Other attempt, same result:
    #New-Item "IIS:\Sites\$WebSiteName\$VirtualFolderName" -type Application -physicalPath $PhysicalPathVirtDir
    
    # Set AppPool
    Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$WebSiteName\$VirtualFolderName" -name applicationPool -value $AppPoolName

    Write-Host "Done."
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there some caching?

Comment: My best guess is that  `New-WebVirtualDirectory` and `ConvertTo-WebApplication` both outputs the target object, so it looks like the same thing twice. Try piping `ConvertTo-WebApplication` to `| Out-Null`

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed as Mathias mentioned.
When playing around with piping to `| Out-Null` for both the Virtual directory and Converting to a WebApplication, I saw the separate outputs.

So, there are two options: discard the output or place the output in a variable and add some text. I choose the last one.

```
function Create-VirtualDirectory-With-AppPool {
    Param (
    [string] $WebSiteName,
    [string] $VirtualFolderName,
    [string] $AppPoolName
    )
    $PhysicalPathWebSite = (Get-Website -Name $WebSiteName | Select-Object).PhysicalPath
    $PhysicalPathVirtDir = "$PhysicalPathWebSite\$VirtualFolderName"

    Write-Host "The following will be created:"
    Write-Host "- Virtual folder: $WebSiteName\$VirtualFolderName with physical path: $PhysicalPathVirtDir"
    Write-Host "- Application: IIS:\Sites\$WebSiteName\$VirtualFolderName"
    Read-Host "Press enter to continue (Ctrl-c to abort)"
        
    $OutputNewvDir = New-WebVirtualDirectory -Site $WebSiteName -Name $VirtualFolderName -PhysicalPath $PhysicalPathVirtDir

    $OutputConvertApp = ConvertTo-WebApplication "IIS:\Sites\$WebSiteName\$VirtualFolderName"
    
    # Set AppPool
    Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$WebSiteName\$VirtualFolderName" -name applicationPool -value $AppPoolName

    Write-Host "New Virtual directory: $($OutputNewvDir | Format-List | Out-String)"
    Write-Host "Convert to Application: $($OutputConvertApp | Format-List | Out-String)"

    Write-Host "Done."
}
```

```
New Virtual directory: 

Name         : V2
PhysicalPath : C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebsite\V2

Convert to Application: 

Path             : /V2
ApplicationPool  : DefaultAppPool
EnabledProtocols : http
PhysicalPath     : C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebsite\V2
```

One strange thing is that both commands have a different number of parameters, but some are shown when output together (as shown in my original question).
But I can live with that, will research that later.